# How to change the text color of a data table in android?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Here's my problem: i load from an XML file some data and put it in a custom class i named Data Table.
When i open it in a Table Layout (the table layout is contained in a scroll-view), the entire text loaded is light gray and difficult to read.
Is there a way to change the color of the text displayed?

The xml is downloaded from a ftp server and dynamically loaded into the tablelayout.

Here's the custon class datatable

```
 public class DataTable {

private Vector<String> _columnNames;
private Vector<Vector<String>> _table;
private String _name;

/**
 * 
 */
public DataTable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    _name = "";

    _columnNames = new Vector<String>(0, 1);
    _table = new Vector<Vector<String>>(0, 1);
}

public void addColumn(String columnName) {
    if (!_columnNames.contains(columnName)) {
        _columnNames.add(columnName);
    }
}

public void addRow() {
    Vector<String> newRow = new Vector<String>(_columnNames.size());
    _table.add(newRow);
}

public void removeRow(int rowIndex) {
    if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < _table.size()) {
        _table.remove(rowIndex);
    }
}

public String getValue(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return _table.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);
}

public String getValue(int rowIndex, String columnName) {
    return getValue(rowIndex, _columnNames.indexOf(columnName));
}

public void setValue(String value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (rowIndex >= _table.size()) {
        rowIndex = _table.size();
        addRow();
    }

    Vector<String> row = _table.get(rowIndex);
    if (columnIndex >= row.size()) {
        row.add(value);
    } else {
        row.setElementAt(value, columnIndex);
    }
}

public void setValue(String value, int rowIndex, String columnName) {
    addColumn(columnName);
    setValue(value, rowIndex, _columnNames.indexOf(columnName));
}

public int rowCount() {
    return _table.size();
}

public int columnCount() {
    if (_table.size() > 0) {
        return _table.get(0).size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public String getName() {
    return _name;
}

public void setName(String tableName) {
    _name = tableName;
}

public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    return _columnNames.get(columnIndex);
}

public Vector<String> getRow(int rowIndex){
    return _table.get(rowIndex);
}
```

And this is the XML file

```
<newdataset>
   <view>
     <label>Codice Ispezione</label>
       <value>AD3008STIs</value>
   </view>

   <view>
     <label>Città</label>
     <value>Roma</value>
   </view>

   <view>
     <label>Tipologia Report</label>
     <value>Totale copertura ultimo comune</value>
   </view>

   <view>
     <label>Causale Ispezione</label>
     <value>Programmazione sito estesa</value>
   </view>
 </newdataset>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the text color of the TextView (android:textColor) that you put your text in? If you post your layout file I can be more detailed.

Comment: I solved it by manually adding this line:    lblLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); where lblLabel is my dynamically generated textview, thanks a lot.